# Basic authentication with GraphQL

Tags: authentication, graphql, apollo-client

I'm receiving this error when trying to query my graphQL API that uses **Basic authentication**:
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

My code to create my networkInterface is:

```
networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: graphQlEndpoint.uri,
    opts: {
      credentials: graphQlEndpoint.credentials
    }
  });

  networkInterface.use([{
    applyMiddleware(req, next) {
      if (!req.options.header) {
        req.options.headers = {};
      }
      req.options.headers.authorization = 'Basic authorizationCode';
      next();
  }
}])
```

I'm guessing the problem here is that before my webapp makes the query, it sends a preflight request and that's where I receive the **error 401**. I was wondering if that was really the reason why I get an error there.

If so, is there a way to fix it?

Is there another authentication thats works better than Basic authentication in this situation?

*note*: I'm using **node.js**, **react**, **apollo-client**

Thank you for any help you can give me.

**EDIT**

```
// Enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing 
app.use('*', cors());

// Authorization: a user authentication is required
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!getAuthUserName(req)) {
    logger('ERROR', 'Unauthorized: authenticated username is missing');
    res.status(401);
    res.send('Unauthorized: Access is denied due to missing credentials');
   }else {
    next();
   }
});

// Print Schema endpoint
app.use(rootUrl + '/schema', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.send(schemaPrinter.printSchema(schema));
});

// Print Introspection Schema endpoint
app.use(rootUrl + '/ischema', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.send(schemaPrinter.printIntrospectionSchema(schema));
});

// Stop node app
if (config.graphql.debugEnabled) {
  app.use(rootUrl + '/stop', (req, res) => {
    logger('INFO', 'Stop request');
    res.send('Stop request initiated');
    process.exit();
  });
}

// GraphQL endpoint
app.use(rootUrl, graphqlExpress(request => {
  const startTime = Date.now();

  request.uuid = uuidV1();
  request.workflow = {
    service: workflowService,
    context: getWorkflowContext(request)
  };
  request.loaders = createLoaders(config.loaders, request);
  request.resolverCount = 0;
  request.logTimeoutError = true;

  logger('INFO', 'new request ' + request.uuid + ' by ' + request.workflow.context.authUserName);

  request.incrementResolverCount =  function () {
    var runTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    if (runTime > config.graphql.queryTimeout) {
      if (request.logTimeoutError) {
        logger('ERROR', 'Request ' + request.uuid + ' query execution timeout');
      }
      request.logTimeoutError = false;
      throw('Query execution has timeout. Field resolution aborted');
    }
    this.resolverCount++;
  };

  return !config.graphql.debugEnabled ?
    {
      schema: schema,
      context: request,
      graphiql: config.graphql.graphiqlEnabled
    } :
    {
      schema: schema,
      context: request,
      graphiql: config.graphql.graphiqlEnabled,
      formatError: error => ({
        message: error.message,
        locations: error.locations,
        stack: error.stack
      }),
      extensions({ document, variables, operationName, result }) {
        return {
          requestId: request.uuid,
          runTime: Date.now() - startTime,
          resolverCount: request.resolverCount,
          operationCount: request.workflow.context.operationCount,
          operationErrorCount:     request.workflow.context.operationErrorCount
        };
      }
    };
}));
```

Comment: Your client code is fine, but you likely need to enable cors on the server side. can you post the code for your node js server? (express I'm guessing?)

Comment: Your guess makes sense but I think it's already enabled. I didn't write it myself but I added in my question the part of the code I think you want to take a look at.

Comment: did you save? not seeing any new code

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated it right after. If any other section would help let me know.

Comment: interesting.. what happens if you change `app.use('*', cors())` to `app.use(cors())`

Comment: Made the change, I get the same error.

Comment: I get 2 errors actually: 1.`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)` and 2.`Fetch API cannot load http://192.168.3.63/myFolder/graphql. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I get these errors before and after your suggested change^^

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding cors at graphql server side also. I am posting here a bit of code.

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin(origin, callback){
        callback(null, true);
    },
    credentials: true
};
graphQLServer.use(cors(corsOptions));
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Accept');
    next();
}
graphQLServer.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

I think this may help you.

Comment: I edited my server's code to add the code you suggested (replacing `graphQLServer.use` by `app.use`) but I still get the same `preflight request doesn't pass access control check` error.

Comment: When I query my **server** from _localhost/graphql_ directly, I get all the headers you added in **allowCrossDomain** in my **Response Headers**. But when I query from my **client**, I get none of those headers in my **Response Headers**.

Comment: @petithomme Have you placed this code section just after app server creation? Some times code placing can make diiference

Comment: I placed it right after the `.start`and right before all the `app.use`. I already had a line with `app.use(cors())` so I placed the code there

Comment: I think the problem might be that **IIS** is blocking my _OPTIONS_ preflight request because it doesn't have the authorization header. I'm looking into finding a way to configure my IIS to return a message with `status 200` after the preflight request.

Answer (score 0):

the graphql server that you are using is declining preflight request which is made by the browser to see if the server is going to accept browser's request. Preflight request is also called `OPTIONS` request.

Server just sends the status code 200. So in addition of CORS snippet that you see, you need to add one more check.

this is cors middleware that you can use in your express applications:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  //--------------OPTIONS-------------
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  next();
};
```